# CSS SVG Filter is not being shown on some monitors on the same system

Tags: css, svg, svg-filters

I have an SVG Filter

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" height="0" width="0">
  <defs>
    <filter id="svgID">
      <feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" baseFrequency="2" numOctaves="3"></feTurbulence>
      <feDisplacementMap in="SourceGraphic" scale="5"></feDisplacementMap>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

I am applying to various elements on a page (using a variety of different methods, from `backdrop-filter: url(#svgID)` to simply `filter: url(#svgID)`

For the most part it is working as expected. What is strange is that I have several people who have tested it and reported that the filter wasn't showing up. Then they move their browser window to a different screen and it starts working. Moving it back to the original screen the filter effect dissapears. Note that the behaviour was observed on the latest non-dev versions of Edge, Safari and Chrome. On both PC and Mac (intel based as well as M1 and M2). The browser in all instances was not resized.

The effect also isn't tied to any media queries.

Comment: Doesn't seem like a programming problem. Seems like a hardware problem.